# Write permissions not getting set when using NIO on unix

Tags: java, permissions, nio, 777

I am using NIO to set permissions on all directories in a path as below. i am trying to give 777 permissions , however the "w" part is not getting applied...Whats wrong here?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions;
import java.util.Set;

public class permissionTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

        Path dirPath = Paths.get("./part1/part2/part3");


        Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx");
        System.out.print(permissions.toString() + ' ');

        FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> fileAttributes = 

                PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(permissions);

        Files.createDirectories(dirPath, fileAttributes);

    }

}

$ ls -ld part1/
drwxr-xr-x 3 * *4096 Oct 30 02:48 part1/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the umask is applied.

Try and type this at the shell:

```
umask 0
```

and then rerun your program (or launch your IDE from the command line and run the code). It also means that if you do `umask 027`, the permissions for your created directories will be 750.

Unfortunately, you cannot change your process' umask (since this is per process, and inherited) in Java itself...

---

Note that there is [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-) to set "absolute" file permissions.

Comment: so, we can do chmod -R but we can't do the same in Java?

Comment: You can change permissions recursively, yes. For this, you'll need to implement a [`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html).

Comment: Note: since this message I've been starting to implement [this](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more); a recursive chmod is planned. Contributions welcome!